# Having problems in logging out from the account using sessions in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, session, logout

I am having problem in session management in my asp.net. I am logging out of the admin and user account, but as i am pressing the forward button of the browser, the page is redirected again to the User/Admin account. I already destroyed the session i created for storing the username, everytime i am clicking the log out button.

Comment: You are having problems with 'Backbutton' refresh I guess

Comment: It sounds like the user might be getting authenticated again via the client-side cookie. Does that go away if you clear the browser cache?

Comment: Any chance your app using an SSO?

Answer (score 0):

In every page you have you should implement a small if sentence in the Page_Load that checks if the Session is null like so:

```
if(Session["User"] == null)
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
```

Make sure that when you log out, you make sure that the Session is set to null.

Comment: Or add that to Masterpage or create a custom base page and add that code on load

Comment: But, think of it this way, what if the page is being loaded from browser cache?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default template of Visual Studio this may help you:

```
if(!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be two problems here:

First Problem (Server Side):

1. Using `Session` to store authentication and authorization is a poor way to design the application. Use the ASP.NET Authorization and Authentication(FormsAuthentication) framework to do this. This way, your application can use client side cookies to store authentication information, and can allow only certain users to access certain pages in your application(using Authorization).
2. `Session` data is lost each time the ASP.NET recycles the application pool(which might happen at random). This is potentially dangerous and can cause `NullReferenceException`s during usage.(This happens if Session management is `inproc` which is the default)

Second Problem (Client Side):

Usually, the browser caches the page, so the `Page_Load` will not be executed on the server side. To work around the problem, you can add this code in `Page_Load` event on each page if you want to(or add it to a Master Page) :

```
 Response.Buffer=true;
 Response.ExpiresAbsolute=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
 Response.Expires =-1500;
 Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
```

And, then, the `Authorization`|`Authentication` part of ASP.NET will gracefully redirect you to `Login.aspx` page, if, the user has been logged out.

Using some more code, you can even redirect to the homepage for a particular user, if the user is already authenticated based on a certain roleID.